# Wordpress not showing upgrade to latest version

Tags: updates

One of my clients has a server with a bunch of Wordpress stand-alone sites all on their own vhosts. We are trying to upgrade to the latest version, but for three of the sites no upgrade is showing in the Admin UI or on the command line. Example:

```
$ wp core version
4.6.1

$ wp core check-update
Success: WordPress is at the latest version.
```

The latest version is 4.9.7. I've updated wp-cli and updated plugins - any other ideas as to what could be causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just came cross this with another client who has a very old Wordpress site (on 4.9.5) that they want us to update and maintain. The solution I found was to update manually via the command line to 5.9, then from there to the latest 6.2.

Here were my steps (after backing up etc)

```
$ cd /var/www/vhosts
$ wget https://wordpress.org/wordpress-5.9.6.tar.gz
$ tar -xzf wordpress-5.9.6.tar.gz
$ cp -r wordpress/* mysite/
$ rm -rf wordpress
```

The go to /wp-admin and it will prompt to run the database update. Then repeat for the latest version:

```
$ wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
$ tar -xzf wordpress-6.2.1.tar.gz
$ cp -r wordpress/* mysite/
$ rm -rf wordpress
```

And go to /wp-admin again. Worked, we are now on 6.2.1 :-)